# Pandas: Count the occurrences of specific value in Column B...and display it in column C

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas dataframe where one of the columns tracks the state an accident occurred in. I want to add a column that totals the number of accidents from that state. For instance, if one of my rows shows an accident that happened in Utah, I want the last column to count the number of accidents in the dataframe that occurred in Utah.

```
model     state     total count
-----     -----     -----------
Ford      Maine          2       
Dodge     Maine          2      
Chevy     Utah           1      
Fiat      Texas          1
```

The code so far, along with failed attempts:

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.read_csv("faainfo.csv")
cols = df.columns
df.drop(columns=cols[15:43], inplace=True)

df = df.loc[df['LOC_CNTRY_NAME'] == 'UNITED STATES']


# LOC_STATE_NAME

states_list = {
    "ALABAMA": "AL",
    "ALASKA": "AK",
    "ARIZONA": "AZ",
    "ARKANSAS": "AR",
    "CALIFORNIA": "CA",
    "COLORADO": "CO",
    "CONNECTICUT": "CT",
    "DELAWARE": "DE",
    "FLORIDA": "FL",
    "GEORGIA": "GA",
    "HAWAII": "HI",
    "IDAHO": "ID",
    "ILLINOIS": "IL",
    "INDIANA": "IN",
    "IOWA": "IA",
    "KANSAS": "KS",
    "KENTUCKY": "KY",
    "LOUISIANA": "LA",
    "MAINE": "ME",
    "MARYLAND": "MD",
    "MASSACHUSETTS": "MA",
    "MICHIGAN": "MI",
    "MINNESOTA": "MN",
    "MISSISSIPPI": "MS",
    "MISSOURI": "MO",
    "MONTANA": "MT",
    "NEBRASKA": "NE",
    "NEVADA": "NV",
    "NEW HAMPSHIRE": "NH",
    "NEW JERSEY": "NJ",
    "NEW MEXICO": "NM",
    "NEW YORK": "NY",
    "NORTH CAROLINA": "NC",
    "NORTH DAKOTA": "ND",
    "OHIO": "OH",
    "OKLAHOMA": "OK",
    "OREGON": "OR",
    "PENNSYLVANIA": "PA",
    "RHODE ISLAND": "RI",
    "SOUTH CAROLINA": "SC",
    "SOUTH DAKOTA": "SD",
    "TENNESSEE": "TN",
    "TEXAS": "TX",
    "UTAH": "UT",
    "VERMONT": "VT",
    "VIRGINIA": "VA",
    "WASHINGTON": "WA",
    "WEST VIRGINIA": "WV",
    "WISCONSIN": "WI",
    "WYOMING": "WY"}

df['states'] = df.LOC_STATE_NAME.map(states_list)

f = df['LOC_STATE_NAME'] == 'ARIZONA'
x = f.sum()
print(x)
# df['FLORIDA'].value_counts()
# counts = df['LOC_STATE_NAME']
# df['stcnt'] = (df['LOC_STATE_NAME'])

df
```

Comment: include a complete working example.

Comment: and your attempts at solving the problem. This is pretty basic stuff that will be covered in any pandas tutorial. SO is not here to do the coding for you. [ask]

Answer (score 0):

You will want to read pandas docs on `assign` and `transform` to understand fully what each is doing.

`transform` returns a series of counts in this case and `assign` will create your new column.

If your data is just columns model and state, try:

```
df = df.assign(total_count = df.groupby(['state']).transform('count'))

   model  state  total_count
1   Ford  Maine            2
2  Dodge  Maine            2
3  Chevy   Utah            1
4   Fiat  Texas            1
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the following error when I tried your solution:

"ValueError: Wrong number of items passed"

I got it to work by adding the 'state' column before the transform:

```
df = df.assign(total_count = df.groupby(['LOC_STATE_NAME'])['LOC_STATE_NAME'].transform('count'))
```

Thank you.